# Java MigLayout Vertical Alignment

Tags: java, swing, vertical-alignment, miglayout

I am attempting to utilize the MigLayout layout manager to create a GUI that allows the user to move items from one list to the other.  I need the arrows to be close together (vertical).  The problem I am running into is that the top arrow is at the top of the cell and I have been unsuccessful in trying to move it down to the bottom.  I'm trying out the Cell feature of MigLayout but I will use whatever works.  Thank you.

```
public class StackCode extends JPanel{
public StackCode(){
    super(new MigLayout());
    JButton run = new JButton("Okay");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

    JList uList = new JList(new String[]{"test1","test2","test3","test4","test5"});
    JList nList = new JList();
    uList.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
    nList.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
    uList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,150));
    nList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,150));

    add(run,"cell 0 0");
    add(cancel,"cell 1 0 4 1");
    add(new JLabel("List1"),"cell 0 1 2 1"); // List1 title label -- cell column row width height
    add(new JLabel("List2"),"cell 4 1 2 1"); // List2 title label
    add(uList,"cell 0 2 2 5"); // JList1
    add(nList,"cell 4 2 2 5"); // JList 2
    add(new JLabel("-->"),"cell 3 3 1 3, align center"); // eventually import arrow image
    add(new JLabel("<--"),"cell 3 6 1 1, align center"); // eventually import arrow image

}
private static void createAndShowGUI(){
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    StackCode newContentPane = new StackCode();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

[image: Desired Graphics]
Edited to include image of desired graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to accomplish this by adding this to the super(new MigLayout()) snippet

```
super(new MigLayout(
            "",
            "",
            "[center][center][b][top]"
            ));
// This sets the 1st/2nd row to center aligned, 3rd row to bottom aligned and the
// 4th row to top aligned.
```

And change this:

```
add(new JLabel("-->"),"cell 3 3 1 3, align center");
add(new JLabel("<--"),"cell 3 6 1 1, align center");
```

To:

```
add(new JLabel("-->"),"cell 3 3 1 1, align center");
add(new JLabel("<--"),"cell 3 4 1 1, align center");
```